# How to query an api in Android?

Tags: android, api, post

is it possible to query a website's api from an android app? If so, how to do you handle the return if it's in xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/twitter-client-for-android-how-to-make-xml-over-http-calls/) showing you how to create a Twitter client using Android should be helpful.

As far as processing the XML, there are lots of ways.  See the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html) for XML support, as well as [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/?S_TACT=105AGX54).

Comment: It seems that requestQueue was taking out of the android sdk or I'm just missing something. Can anyone confirm this?